How to extract audio files from KJOS IPS application/program?
Unfortunately I bought Bastien "Piano for Adults 1" book which comes, unlike other books, not directly with audio files per se, but with app/program KJOS IPS, which manages those files.
Since this app/program is slow and unresponsive I would very much prefer to copy those files and play them in regular media player like VLC. But, I can only see one option provided within the app, to copy accompaniment audio files, while I need performance/student files.
The app for sure stores those files somewhere, but where? Or conversely, how to copy/extract them?
I have both Windows version and Android version.
Updates: I've already contacted publisher.

First I would try to contact the app support; this kind of digging around is neither fun nor guaranteed to succeed. (They might simply have chosen an exotic format not directly understood by anything else.)

J.W. Pepper's web page claims accompaniment files are MP3, so I'd start by scanning directories like /library or the KJOS directory itself for *.mp3 to see what shows up.  It would be a bit odd for Kjos to have bothered to create a special format for the performance audio files.

No idea whether the answer of ChatGPT will help. This is just a test!

@AlbrechtHügli whle the answer is kind of obvious, I realized I indeed should repeat all the steps for the Adroid as well. The app is multiplatform, but Android itself is more constrained for the app. We will see...

ChatGPT:

Extracting audio files from an app like KJOS IPS can be tricky, especially if the files are not explicitly accessible. Here are some steps you can try to locate and extract the files on both Windows and
Android versions:
For Windows Version
Check Installation Directory:
Locate the KJOS IPS app installation folder (e.g., C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files (x86)).  Look for folders named Audio, Assets, or similar. Files might be in common audio formats like .mp3, .wav, or possibly proprietary formats.
Search Using File Explorer:
Open File Explorer and search within the app directory using keywords like *.mp3, *.wav, or *.ogg.  If nothing shows up, include hidden files by enabling "Show hidden files" in Windows Explorer settings.
Monitor File Access During Playback:
Use a tool like Process Monitor to track file access by the app while it plays the audio. This can reveal the path where the audio files are stored or temporarily extracted.
Check App Data Folders:
Audio files might be stored in user-specific folders like:
C:\Users\[YourUsername]\AppData\Local\[AppName]\
C:\Users\[YourUsername]\AppData\Roaming\[AppName]\
Again, search for audio files in these directories.
For Android Version
Check App Storage:
Connect your Android device to a computer.
Navigate to Android/data/com.kjos.ips or a similar folder in the internal storage.
Look for files, assets, or other directories containing audio files.
Explore Using a File Manager:
Use a file manager app like Solid Explorer or ES File Explorer on your device.
Search the device storage for possible audio file extensions (.mp3, .wav, etc.).
Extract Audio Using Backup:
Backup the app using ADB (Android Debug Bridge) or apps like Titanium Backup (requires root).
Extract the backup and inspect its contents for audio files.
Decompile the App:
If the files are embedded in the app, you can decompile it using tools like APKTool to access the assets or res/raw folder.
Note: This is an advanced method and might breach licensing agreements.
Additional Notes
Publisher Assistance:
If you've contacted the publisher, they might offer an official way to access the performance files or troubleshoot the app.
Legal Boundaries:
Ensure that any extraction method you use complies with the app's terms of service and copyright laws.
If these steps don’t work, share more details about what you’ve tried, and I can guide further.

